# Laravel 4: pointing a form to a controller function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I can't understand, how to set up the Form action to direct to a function of a specific controller.

This is my blade code:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route'=>'user.search')) }}
```

But I get this error :

```
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "user.search" as such route does not exist.
```

the controller (`UserController`) has a function with this prototype

```
public function search(){ ... }
```

I have also tried to set up a route like this in route.php

```
Route::post('user/search', 'UserController@search');
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like

```
{{ Form::open( array('url' => URL::to('user/search')) ) }}
```

Because you don't have a name for the `route`. To define a name for the route, use following syntax,

```
Route::post('user/search', array( 'as' => 'userSearch', 'uses' => 'UserController@search' ));
```

So, you can use the route by it's name, as

```
{{ Form::open( array('route' => 'userSearch') ) }} // 'search' method will be invoked
```

Also, you can directly use the `action` of a controller as

```
{{ Form::open( array('action' => 'UserController@search') ) }}
```

Check [Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) and [Form](http://laravel.com/docs/html).